# Changing the block layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

New to Drupal; Went through some tutorials. I understand the concept of content types and blocks. I have installed the Nexus theme. The only way I know to add content is through content types and blocks.

I want to change the block layout for each page, but I am stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverlow community

You could start on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming.

If you want to create different layouts on arbitrary pages of your site, using a graphical interface, you could have a look at the [authoring experience demo from 8.6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JUklJHbFBo) to get an idea of what is possible with Drupal. But this module is not considered *stable* yet, it is still under development (you can check the progress at "[Add a Layout Builder to core](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/2884601)")

A popular module to work with layouts is [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer), but it has a learning curve. In the project page they recommend these tutorials:

- Jackson River put together a tutorial explaining [how to build landing pages using Panelizer](http://www.jacksonriver.com/blog/drupal-panelizer-architecting-landing-pages).
- The module was covered in Code Karate's [Daily Dose of Drupal series](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-panelizer-module).
- OSTraining have a tutorial that also mentions creating alternative displays.
  [link](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/panelizer/)
- Drupalize.me updated their Panels series to introduce Panelizer (commercial training video) 
  [link](https://drupalize.me/videos/attaching-panels-any-content-or-entity-using-panelizer?p=1137).
- Tim Eisenhuth from PreviousNext put together an article explaining how to programmatically modify Panelizer displays  [link](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/updating-panelizer-content-programmatically).

It seems that your are new to Drupal and are trying to build a whole website by yourself.

You can have an idea of the concepts and topics involved in creating a website with Drupal by reviwing the *[Acquia Certified Site Builder Exam Blueprint– D8](https://www.acquia.com/customer-success/learning-services/acquia-certification-program)*.